# Why Redis removes relations in objects if related object is removed from database?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, caching, redis

I have Django, PostgreSQL and Redis. I have models that have foreign keys and m2m relationships. Every day I'm caching bunch of objects and dropping their cache at midnight. The problem is when I'm removing object from the database (during the day) - the fields with relationships in cache are also getting changed (id of this objects is removed from foreign keys and m2m). As I read in Redis docs - all objects are stored as Hashes in the server's RAM. I can't understand how database changes could affect to the RAM cache. So why it happens and how can I prevent such behaviour?

Example:

```
# Model
class Item(models.Model):
    ...
    places = models.ManyToManyField(Place, verbose_name=_('Places'), related_name='items', null=True, blank=True)


# In view
items = Item.objects.all()
cache.set(key, items, None)
```

then in django admin I'm removing one of the Places and in shell I'm getting  cached Items:

```
items = cache.get(key)
```

and manually checking the places of retrieved Items - the place has been removed from all related items. And this is not good.

Comment: You aren't providing enough detail. How, exactly, are you doing what you're doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django is removing it because you told it to. You are using a relational mapping in Django, then telling it to delete one of those items, which it rightly then does.

This is explained in the docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/relations/

Also, calling an item.objects.all() executes a query to the SQL db, rather than using what is in the cache. This is because you are operating, at that point, on the ORM rather than the cache. Related, storing your "items" result in the cache only caches the result, not all related items.

Comment: Django removes relationships from database, but relationships in cache should be not affected, but they are. I'm checking cached 'items' immediately after removing 'place' from db.

Comment: How, exactly are you "manually checking the places of retrieved Items"? Are you iteration over what is in the cache and asking Django for them? Is the string you get back from item.get(key) the same as you put into it?

Comment: How, exactly are you "manually checking the places of retrieved Items"? What does "... removed from all related items" mean exactly?
Redis is unable to do what you say it is doing, therefore either Django is updating your cache or you're not caching what you think you are caching. 
Without specific details we can't say. For all we know the UpdateCacheMiddleware is updating the cache for you, or you're not caching anything more than a list of items. You don't provide enough details to know.

Comment: Wow, I'm dumb, sorry. I've saved objects not like strings, I've saved a QuerySet to cache, and after getting particular item form cache I made "cached_item.objects.all()" which made a SELECT query to database. So that's why I can't find related place - it haven't been cached with items. Please, add the note that related items are not cached when you caching a QuerySet and I'll approve your answer. And I have additional question - is there are some difference between items = Item.objects.all() and items = list(Item.objects.all())? Thanks!

Comment: Not dumb, just not aware that making method calls to the object's manager operates on the ORM even if you've pulled it from cache. I've added that and verbiage regarding the cache not caching related data.